PlatformIO ESP32 Upload filesystem image with app
I used PlatformIO within Visual Studio to write an app for an esp32 chip. The app is complete and I now need to copy it to 200+ boards.
Is there a way to automate the upload? Ideally I just plug it in and it starts copying the data
If that isn't an option is there a way to simultaneously upload both the app and the filesystem image so I don't have to sit in front of the computer and wait for the first part to complete so I can do the second part.
It is currently taking a little over 2 minutes each, which translates to about 7 hours. Hoping to not sit and stare at the screen for that long.
I've looked through docs for both platformio and visual studio and am not having any luck. I assumed it was at least an option with visual studio.

I got part way there and wrote a powershell script that streamlines it some
C:\Users\USERNAME\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run --target uploadfs --environment WT32-SC01-PLUS 
C:\Users\USERNAME\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run --target upload --environment WT32-SC01-PLUS

